# Problem escaping HTML characters in JavaScript for page output

Tags: php, javascript, html, escaping, character

I was told that escaping HTML characters before entering them into a DB is a bad idea, so I have been modifying my code so that the raw input is stored without escaping.  Now I am having a problem outputting the data onto a web page.

In PHP, I use htmlentities() for my output and it works fine, but I am using AJAX to retrieve my data, and thus have to output using JavaScript.

I have tried using the escape() function in JS but my output is not coming out properly.  The sample text that I am using to test is:

**One, two, & three**

I know that it is the ampersand causing issues so my first question is - how do I escape this for output using JS?  When I remove it, I get this:

**One,%20,two,%20three**

... so my second question is, what am I doing wrong here?

Any ideas?  I'm sure this is simple for many of you.

Comment: Mmh why don't you use `htmlentities()` for the Ajax response as well (when the response is generated at the server side)?

Comment: Thats it ;-) The page, which is called by Ajax should output it with htmlentities() or htmlspecialchars(). If not possible why ever there are so much htmlspecialchars or htmlentities scripts with javascript, e.g: http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars  or http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities

Comment: thank you both for your reply.  it seems like it takes another person or person(s) to make you realize the answer is so simple =].  Ahmet - thanks for that reference.  I didn't know JS translations of PHP functions actually existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(as it seems to have helped you, I will put it as a proper answer)*

You can still use `htmlentities()` if you use Ajax. Just use it for the response that is generated on the server, like you would if you returned HTML. There is no difference.